# Error while installing flutter

Tags: dart, cross-platform, flutter

```
$ flutter doctor
```

Downloading Dart SDK 2.0.0-dev.16.0...
Unknown operating system. Cannot install Dart SDK.

error got shown up,why it occurs.

Comment: `2.0.0-dev.16.0` sounds old. Can you try purging the Flutter install directory and start over again according to the instructions?

Comment: tried as of [link](https://medium.com/@develodroid/flutter-i-intro-and-install-a8bf6dfcc7c8) same error repeated

Comment: What's your current version? https://flutter.io/get-started/install/ is the officiak site

Comment: got the issue it's with the powershell were the Environment path not set. thank you

Comment: How did you solve the issue? I have added the path to the environment itself but having the same issue.

Comment: just restart after adding the variables.

Answer (score 14):

$ flutter doctor

Run this command in either a Command Prompt or PowerShell window. Currently, Flutter does not support third-party shells like Git Bash.

Answer (score 3):

go to

**windows power shell->
right click->run as administrator->type `flutter doctor`**

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue, the only way I fixed it was removing my download of the flutter SDK, redownloading it and pointing my path variable to my new installation.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of Path issue of other command props(like git bash etc.). So if you will use Windows Comand promp it would work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use MINGW or cygwin in window, you can face this problem.
Let try flutter on cmd.

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown in `Git Bash` where currently it is not support. Try using Windows Powershell or command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

It's an error from git bash cmd, so:

1. run cmd prompt as administrator
2. run flutter doctor

Problem solved, Dart would start downloading.